# WooCommerce: Assigning Multiple Values to the same Product Variation Attribute Key

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am currently struggling with setting up product variations as a means of compressing a product catalog.. We currently have several thousand individual product pages and variations, and I am looking for a way to compress each product type into a single variation. The products sold are vehicle-related, and as a result are tailored to fit each model year-range:

```
                       Make                Model                Year        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Body Style A       RAM                 1500                 2002     
                       RAM                 1500                 2003
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Body Style B       RAM                 1500                 2016     
                       RAM                 1500                 2017     
                       RAM                 1500                 2018     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Body Style C       RAM                 1500                 2019
```

WooCommerce's canned variable products create a new variation for each combination of attributes. For example, "Body Style A" will create two identical variations where I would prefer to have one, which picks up on the "Year" being 2002 OR 2003, instead of assigning only one value.

[Please click HERE to view the interface and an example of what I mean by saying two variations will/should point to an identical variation...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/783F8.jpg)

Now, I have considered just using year ranges but this will not make it any less convolutes as year ranges vary between vehicles (ie. Ram 1500: 2002-2009, 2010-2018, 2019+ // Toyota Tacoma: 05-15, 16+, and so on..) and I would like to maintain individual vehicle years for use across the site.

My ideal output would look something like..:

[This variable product mockup here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMVej.jpg)

I've tried forcing the field to accept multiple values (using an arry, x OR y OR z value approach, etc.) but have not had any luck as the variations outputted only accept the first value and not those that follow.

Can anyone point me to where this data is stored/handled, or how to approach overriding this field accepting a single value only so that I might allow it to accept multiple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the same price for multiple years as on your "ideal output", a smart possible way should be:

1. to disable "used for variations" option from the "Years" attribute for the variable product,
2. to keep all your selected year values in the "Years" product attribute
3. to set on your variable product a custom field dropdown, that will get the years values *(this dropdown will have the same look as your other dropdowns)*.

Then you will be able to add the selected year as custom cart item data when the product is added to cart...

This will really reduce the number of product variations, but it will only work if there is no prices difference between those years.